# Sorting API response in JSON format before passing to props in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am trying to figure out how to sort the API response alphabetically by store name before storing the results in the component's state `apiResults: []`

Here is my code that is called when a form is submitted or button is clicked

```
getStores() {
        let userZip = this.state.userInput;
        const api = "some api";
        return fetch(api + userZip)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            //sort array alphabetically by store name
            //Add code below this line
            responseJson = sort()???
            // Add code above this line
            this.setState({
                apiResults: responseJson
            });
            console.log(this.state.apiResults);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });  
      }
```

Here is the sample JSON that I am using.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "code": "35203",
    "launch_date": "2016-01-29T00:00:00.000-05:00",
    "metro_name": "Birmingham",
    "stores": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Target",
            "launch_date": "2018-01-24T00:00:00.000-05:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Costco",
            "launch_date": "2017-08-14T00:00:00.000-05:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Winn Dixie",
            "launch_date": "2018-11-29T00:00:00.000-05:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Piggly Wiggly",
            "launch_date": "2018-04-10T00:00:00.000-05:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do this

```
responseJson.stores.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Take a look at my codepen https://codepen.io/ulrichdohou/pen/ERbYRX?editors=0010

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much that worked like a charm!

Comment: Happy coding bro

Comment: `responseJson.stores.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0;
                    });`

Comment: Yeah thats the same thing in fact. But yours should run faster than mine because you have omited some steps. I will update to make it shorter

Comment: No problem. I knew it should have been something simple but I have been trying to figure that one out for awhile now. haha. Thanks for the support man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173273/discussion-between-ulrich-dohou-and-daniel-bailey).

Answer (score 0):

create an empty jsonarray object traverse through responsejson.stores and do the sorting and get the sorted output in empty array later on remove the store data and push the sorted array in responsejson.stores

Answer (score 0):

You can use loadash for this.

```
const sortedResponse = _.orderBy(responseJson, r => r.stores.name, ['asc'])
```